# Ruby lint error what is the right way to write this with a guard clause

Tags: ruby, lint, rubocop

Trying to run a command, if success continue on, if failure raise error and send commands output to console.

```
output = `#{command}`
unless $CHILD_STATUS.success?
  raise "#{command} failed with:\n#{output}"
end

C: Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression.
```

the code functions correctly but, rubocop doesn't like it.  What would be the best way to improve the style of this code and still give me the same functionality?

Comment: Is this inside a method? We need some more context to modify it to satisfy Rubocup's suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
raise "#{command} failed with:\n#{output}" unless $CHILD_STATUS.success?
```

Comment: Ok, I don't know why but I was trying to force the output assignment into the unless statement.  I guess I didn't quite understand what the rubocop/style suggestion was saying.  This is a lot cleaner though.